# datatables is not working when fetching data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using DataTables to have a pagination.

I think I set the script correctly, since I followed the instruction in their website. But feel free to pinpoint if there's any wrong/mistake to the indicated script link

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin Reservation Management</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
    </script>
    <!--Custom Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        td,tr {
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 45%;
        }
        th{
            text-align: center;
        }
        form {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>

</head>
```

And now this is my table and stuff, I am fetching the datas from my database.

I did some research here in Stackoverflow, regarding to this issue and the results that I've found was they did not put  and  which I included, but feel free to pinpoint if I haven't included any.*

**php**

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">
    <div class="row">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"> <em class="fa fa-home"></em></a></li>
            <li class="active">Manage Room</li>
        </ol>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <br>
            <h3> Super Admin Reservation Management </h3>
            <hr>
<!-- ################### FUNCTIONALITY ####################### -->
<!-- ################### FUNCTIONALITY ####################### -->
            <div class="container">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable" style="background-color: white;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> Room Number</th>
                            <th> Room Availability </th>
                            <th> Action </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
<!-- ############################################# FETCHING DATA FROM THE DATABASE ######################################################### -->
    <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'db_hotelreservation');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE room_status = 'Pending' OR room_status ='Booked'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
    if($resultCheck > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {

            ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['ID'];?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['room_number']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['room_status'];?></td>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['room_type'];?> </td>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['first_name'] . " " .$row['last_name']?> </td>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['check_in'];?> </td>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['check_out'];?> </td>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['contact_number'];?> </td>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['numberof_days'] ." ". "day/s";?> </td>
                    <td style="display: none;"> <?php echo $row['calculated_price'];?> </td>
                    <td> 
                    <form action="approve.php" method="POST" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Approve this Booking?');">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>" style="">
                        <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve">
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary viewbtn">View Details</button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "No Records Found";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
            </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Javascript and php works in a different environment. It would be clear what went wrong if you can produce the HTML output of your PHP code. I guess <tbody> should be outside of the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code is very hard to review as is. Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and also review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would also consider removing the PHP from the page itself. In this way you can write your PHP script as a stand alone script. DataTables can then call this script to get the data and populate the table.

Comment: @Nik aloha, i tried moving the tbody outside the the php itself and put it on the html. and i don't know how to put image here to show yout the html output.

Comment: @Twisty hello, thanks for the respond. I have not yet tried removing the php itself, so im kinda confused on how to do it.

Comment: @miyaneah Open your browser and point to your page. Then RIght click and `View page source` (Ctrl+U). Paste your html source in your question above..

Comment: @Nik Should i paste everything? because if the html source only and I guess that's it. I copied it in view page source.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of delayed data binding, you can try datatable ajax approach to bind the data. Refer [datatable option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data).